# strange breakpoint in c++, visual studio draws flower around it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, breakpoints

I have no idea what I am asking about, I tried to google the issue but I found nothing because I didn't knew what to search for exactly.

I have some class in c++ , it's doesn't do anything special, while I'm in run time I'm trying to put a breakpoint in one of it's functions and it does the following:

1. Visual studio 2005 takes 100% cpu
2. the cursor (not the mouse, but the blinking thing that you see when you type) is blinking 100 times faster then usual.
3. around the breakpoint visual studio draws in slow motion 4 small half circles one in each corner which makes it look like it draws a flower.
4. when he finish drawing the flower every thing back to normal (the cursor and cpu)

Clues and info I collected about the phenomena:

1. there are sevral functions in the class that do it, and sevral that not.
2. I didn't found any pattern in when he (vs2005) decides to do and when he is not.
3. I checked it in another computer on the same code, and he did it too
4. when I'm not in run time and the program is stopped, this doesn't happen and the breakpoints appear normally

Unfortunately I cannot copy the code here because I don't have internet access at my work, but the class doesn't do anything special.

Has anyone ever seen this phenomena?

Comment: At the point where you call the behavior of a computer program a "phenomenon", you are heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.

Comment: I don't think SO is the appropriate place to get workarounds for IDE bugs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that screen snapshot doesn't work when this is happening.

Comment: The 'blinking thing' is called "caret".  Never seen any flowers.  This kind of "takes a while, 100% core" behavior can happen when you set a breakpoint on a function that's heavily inlined.  The debugger is forced to set a breakpoint on every location in the code where the function is used.  That's slow and makes the UI unresponsive.

Comment: This sounds like a custom margin indicator - see if turning off any add-ins you have solves the problem (or at least narrows down what's responsible): Tools/Add-in Manager.

Comment: Do you happen to be RDP'ed to the box where you are writing code?

Comment: i don't know what is RDP, so i can't answer your question, i tried to find a pic of this thing in google but there is nothing

Comment: No i didn't use remote desktop, it's on my computer at work.

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen this.  Can you add some functions which cover all of the function type combination (inline, static, virtual) etc and see whether there is a pattern to when this happens?  Are you using add ins like Visuals Assit etc?